# Why is my program printing this C-String?

Tags: c, shell, c-strings

I'm currently working on a project for my Operating Systems class and have found a weird error where when printing the string produced when processing the text a user enters in the command line. Here is the output of the program:

```
JR > help
H�E�����UH��SH��(H�}��E�
```

Here is the cope that produces this output:

```
/*
* File: hw3.c
* Purpose: To demonstrate a shell by allowing a user to enter commands 
* and perform actions depending on the command.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Function Prototypes */
void printPrompt();
char* parseCommand(char* cmd);
char* readCommandLine();

/*
 * Entry point of the program.
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    while(1) {
        printPrompt();

        char* cmdLine = readCommandLine();
        char* cmd = parseCommand(cmdLine);

        printf("Selected Command: %s", cmd);
    }
}

/*
 * This function prints a prompt to the user to enter a command.
 */
void printPrompt() {
    printf("\n%s", "JR > ");
}

/**
 * This function reads the command the user enters from the terminal.
 */
char* readCommandLine() {
    char* input = malloc(10);
    
    fgets(input, 10, stdin);

    return input;
}

char* parseCommand(char* cmd) { 
    char *selectedCommand; /* The command to return */

    /* Convert cmd to all lowercase and store it in enteredCommand. */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(cmd); i++)
        cmd[i] = tolower(cmd[i]);

    if (strcmp(cmd, "cd") == 0)
        selectedCommand = "cd";
    else if(strcmp(cmd, "help") == 0)
        selectedCommand = "help";
    else if(strcmp(cmd, "pwd") == 0)
        selectedCommand = "pwd";
    else if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0)
        selectedCommand = "exit";

    return selectedCommand;
}
```

Can anyone explain why the printf() function is printing this?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if nothing matches? You return junk. It's possible you're trying to compare `"help\n"` and it fails to match, returning an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: fgets includes a trailing newline

Comment: Tip: Try not to use microscopic buffers. Instead use 1024 as a default, and go up from there as necessary. 10 bytes is absolutely ridiculous and sets yourself up for overflow bugs when you use even a moderately long command name or later add arguments, like `"list names"` is too long, that's 10 characters and your buffer can only hold 9 + NUL terminator.

Comment: @tadman That's exactly what the problem was. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems here:

- [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is documented as "if a newline character is found...`str` will contain that newline character" so you're actually getting `"help\n"` as an input. You need to strip that newline or anticipate it.
- Your `if` chain fails to address the case when none of those match. You should have a default `return NULL` handler.

I'd rewrite that chunk to be safer, like this:

```c
char* parseCommand(char* cmd) { 
    // Move declaration inside of for()
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(cmd); i++)
        cmd[i] = tolower(cmd[i]);

    if (strcmp(cmd, "cd") == 0)
        return "cd";
    else if(strcmp(cmd, "help") == 0)
        return "help";
    else if(strcmp(cmd, "pwd") == 0)
        return "pwd";
    else if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0)
        return "exit";

    return NULL;
}
```

Where now there's no chance of it falling out the bottom in an inconsistent state.

Technically those could all be simple `if` statements now, the `else` is already expressed by virtue of the `return`.